# Markdown or WYSIWYG editor for Pug Template using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using PUG template with Nodejs and MongoDB.

My code:

*When I use:*

```
// Load Article content
.p #{articleBody}
```

*then* the HTML elements such as, `<b>, <br/>` etcs...

are not parsed. But when I use:

```
// Load Article content
.p !{articleBody}
```

all the HTML elements are parsed and output text are formatted depending upon what HTML tags are used.

Now the question is:

- How do I have MARKDOWN or WYSIWYG with PUG so that I do not have to enter those HTML elements.
- How do I disable `script`, `XSS` or any vulnerability tags? If someone enters it then instead of parsing, I want to simply output the entire text/code.

the following code:

```
.p !{articleBody}
```

enables everything and even run `<script> alert("alert message") </script>` on page load. But I only want simple HTML elements to parse such as, `<b>, <i>, <u>, <img />, <br />` and so on...

Comment: you'll have to remove the script tags and other tags which you don't need before saving the content in your database so that when pug templating is done then those tags aren't present

Comment: @Ammar what if its a comment(s) entered by website users? I can't ask them not to put `script` tags...